# How to refresh the inner tabs in native base?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am having a native base tab in the home screen called `HomeTab` and in HomeTab I have 4 tabs. The second tab in HomeTab has a child tab called `MyTab`. The problem is when I try to refresh the inner tab, that is the MyTab, it takes me to HomeTab's first page. This is how I tried to refresh:
`this.props.navigation.replace('MyTab')`. I thought it will take me to the first tab of MyTab. Instead, it took me to the first tab of HomeTab. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: can you share the home screen code with me so that we can check the functioning

Comment: `<Tabs
          locked={true}
          onChangeTab={this.tabChanged.bind(this)}
          tabBarPosition="bottom"
          tabBarUnderlineStyle={[styles.underLine]}>
<Tab heading="Tab1">
{this.state.activeTab === 0 ? (
              <Tab1 navigation={this.props.navigation} />
            ) : null}
</Tab>
<Tab heading="MyTab">
{this.state.activeTab === 0 ? (
              <MyTab navigation={this.props.navigation} />
            ) : null}
</Tab>`

Something like this.

Comment: So you want to refresh every tab when you open them

Comment: Nope. That's working fine. I'm having a modal in the tabs. When the modal is closed, it modifies the value in the tab. I just need to refresh the tabs when the modal is closed so that the tab contents will get updated.

Comment: so can you show me the close event of modal

Comment: `closeFilterDialog(value) {
    this.setState({
      filterModalVisible: false,
      filteredData: value,
    });
}`

Here the value is to be updated in the tab.

Comment: **this.props.navigation.navigate('MyTab')** use this instead 0f **this.props.navigation.replace('MyTab')**

Comment: @AnujSharma, I tried that too. It just takes me to the particular tab. But not getting refreshed. When I use replace, It takes me to the parent tab's first tab. So these two are now working for this scenario.

Comment: **import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';**                                
<View> **<NavigationEvents
            onDidFocus={() => alert("Refreshed")}
          />**
<Tabs> </Tab>                                                                                                                                                                                   <View>

Comment: use this with **this.props.navigation.navigate('MyTab')**  **NavigationEvents** it will refresh and update data everytime you open a tab

Comment: I just tried with:
`<NavigationEvents onDidFocus={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MyTab')} />
<Tabs><Tab></Tab></Tabs>`

But no luck.

Comment: you just have to set this by default you dont have any need to put navigation in it as it only refresh your page when you click on save butoon in modal